# Generated Google search links can contain the body: or title: operators

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, google

If you use the site search and get [0 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22millennium%20hand%20and%20shrimp%22), you're presented with a handy link to re-try your search with Google:

> Alternately, try your search in Google:
>
> [**http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com/questions "millennium hand and shrimp"**](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com/questions%20%22millennium%20hand%20and%20shrimp%22)

If you use any operators, this link [isn't shown](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22millennium%20hand%20and%20shrimp%22%20hasaccepted:1), presumably because Google can't really do things like `hasaccepted:1`.

*However*, the body: and title: operators are somehow not accounted for, and [the link is still shown](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=body:%22millennium%20hand%20and%20shrimp%22) if they're used. This makes the link somewhat less useful because:

- Google plain doesn't understand body: and counts it as a search term.
- Google does understand title:, but not as you'd expect. It's not valid for web searches, so the search terms will simply be dropped.

This could be fixed by suppressing the Google link if these operators are used, or simply rewriting them to their rough Google equivalents: `intitle:` and `intext:`.

Comment: Also I'm stupid, this question showed up in my "zero results" example link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the next build, we won't render a google search link in these cases.  If you're smart enough to use these operators...you're smart enough to handle google.

While we *could* convert them to the google versions, they're just not equivalent, so it's a bit misleading to do so.  I'd rather be safe here, especially since big back-end search changes/improvements may be on the horizon.